# Does Pierre stay dead if I kill him?

Tags: monaco

Throughout most levels, you may come across a guard named Pierre who is writing a message to his mother (or in one of them, a girl writing to a friend about how all this guy Pierre can talk about is fish and cheese). As a running gag, it's pretty effective. However, since Pierre is, after all, a guard, he is at odds with the thieving crew, and can become antagonistic to the crew if they catch his attention.

This leads to the logical conclusion that one may, if carrying a weapon, kill Pierre.

He appears in new levels thanks to the thieves' actions, which cause him to be fired from his current job, so it's possible he might disappear or be replaced if killed. Then again, guards seem to be able to revive their own through some magic grisly process I don't understand (or care to).

So, in the campaign, if you kill Pierre, does he show up in later levels to write more messages?

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to check this yourself ? I am almost 100% sure that he would still appear because death is not permanents for the guards in Monaco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Death is a temporary state in Monaco.**

As you mentioned, guards can revive other guards, just as players can revive other players in multiplayer mode. Even in singleplayer mode, if all four characters die, "justice is served", which means they get arrested, not killed (there is no death penalty in Monaco, [since its abolition in 1962, the year of the last exectution was 1847](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_capital_punishment_by_country#Europe)).